# Flash Compiler Does Not Allow Overriding

Tags: flash, ant, compiler-errors, exec

I have been assigned to work on a Java/Flash/BlazeDS project. When I pull down the project code, I need to run an Ant script as part of the setup. This script eventually compiles the Flash code, as seen below.

```
<exec executable='"@{sdk}/bin/mxmlc.exe"' failonerror="true" >
    //A bunch of <arg> tags
</exec>
```

The `sdk` attribute used above points to a common folder that our company requires us to use. The path ends in `/sdks/4.1.0`.

This Ant script is failing on the following error.

```
Method marked override must override another method.
override public function getPropertyType(propertyName:String):String
```

The classes that are having the error extend [AbstractEntityMetadata](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/com/adobe/fiber/valueobjects/AbstractEntityMetadata.html), which according to the API, does indeed have a `getPropertyType` function. But it looks like it might have been added in "Adobe Digital Enterprise Platform Data Services for Java EE 4.5".

I am guessing that the `/sdks/4.1.0` is to blame. However, I pointed the `sdk` path to my FlashBuilder 4.5's `/sdks/4.5.1` directory, and I still get the same errors.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: Sure that the Enterprise Platform Data Services are part of the standard SDK?  From what the API doc looks like, it seems like they come with LiveCycle DS...

Comment: Using a different mxmlc probably won't make a difference since it's still a mxml compiler and the error you're seeing is due to something in the swc dependencies that is attempting to be overridden by something in your source.  In your section with a bunch of args does it specify the swcs to use?  I wrote a little java app that will search through all swcs that a project depends on (using eclipse properties file to get the list of swcs) then it opens each and looks for a class in the catalog.xml, you can open the swc with any compression program and check out the catalog.xml to see where it is

Comment: I've been looking for a little while here trying to find where that AbstractEntityMetadata is actually compiled in (or at least referenced) in the framework swcs and I'm not finding it anywhere, looking for fiber.swc in the root of my SDKs folder I don't find it, googling I do however... looks like this may be your issue, this dependencies needs to be present or you'll see those errors http://help.adobe.com/en_US/LiveCycleDataServicesES/3.1/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811f00f6e5f6-7ffbUpdate.html

Comment: Sorry for the delay. @shaunhusain In my `<arg>` tags, there are a bunch of `-compiler.library-path` values. One of these points to the "libs" directory, which holds the SWCs mentioned in your link (except the AIR one). There are also other copies of those SWCs that are being referenced in different `<arg>` tags. The `fiber.swc` seems to hold the `AbstractEntityMetadata`. In both of these SWCs, the following is seen in `catalog.xml`: `<script name="com/adobe/fiber/valueobjects/AbstractEntityMetadata" mod="1268685508325" signatureChecksum="2559815443">`.

Comment: I switched out my `libs\fiber.swc` file. I changed it from the one pulled down with the code to the one located in my FlashBuilder's `eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.5.1.313231\fiberSwcs\4.5\libs` directory. The Ant script passed, but on starting up Tomcat I get a "Send Failed" alert in the Flash player, and the data seems to not be connected.

Comment: The "Send Failed" seems to have just been a Tomcat setup issue. I fixed that and am now getting a `Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)` exception when I load the application locally.

Comment: Hrm. I cannot seem to reproduce that error now. So it seems to be working. @shaunhusain If you outline your help in an answer I will mark it as correct. Do you see any potential issues with the SWC file switch I did? Like anything that might be wrong but not immediately noticeable?

Comment: You should not change the libraries that came with your IDE. You can change the entire SDK, or include external SWCs, for each project: open your project properties and go to "Build Path".

Comment: @weltraumpirat That's basically what I did. I copied the IDE's fiber.swc into my project's `lib` folder (which is being used in the build path).

Comment: @shaunhusain Ended up answering. Will change if you ever come back.

Comment: @RachelG. Hi sorry I don't have a clear answer as to whether or not this will cause other problems.  The swc to be included should have been somehow specified in the ant script, it may have been assumed that it would be loaded as a part of the SDK specified, it's difficult for me to say this was the absolutely correct course of action without having been the person who set it up in the first place, answering your own, if it worked, is okay with me.  Sorry I get involved in like 10 questions at once, beyond my day job, and don't always manage my time well.  Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `libs\fiber.swc` file with a newer version. You could use the one in your FlashBuilder's `eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.5.1.313231\fiberSwcs\4.5\libs` folder.